# java char implicit conversion to double?

Tags: java

Why this is possible?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int total = 4;
    double average = (char) total; // *****
    System.out.println("Total: \n "+ average);
}
```

this will output 4.0

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Your proposed duplicate was an inverse.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: yes, the question is an inverse, but the answer covers this question, and that is what matters

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @user207421 You can't, implicitly or explicitly, cast a `boolean` to `double`, even though internally it's just a zero or a one. The Java language designed made the choice to treat a `char` as a numeric type but they could have have chosen to make it more special so that it can't be cast to a numeric type, or only using an explicit cast. It's not so strange to think that a character is not the same as a number.